# Can you use an object literal as key for another object literal? What are the implications of doing this?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to access items on an object literal where each key is set to a unique identifier.

Using an object reference seems like an effective way as the value would be looked up by the object reference.

I realise there are symbols, however they don't have support on IE.

The following works, but what are the implications of doing this? What's the support like? I'm finding it challenging to find information on this.

```
const myKey = {}
const target = { [myKey]: 'value' }
console.log(target[myKey])
```

Comment: it performs a `toString` and insert this value as key. what do you expect instead?

Comment: You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) if you want to use an object as a key without converting it to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property names can be Symbols or Strings. Anything else will be cast to a string.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
const target = { [myKey.toString()]: 'value' }
```

… so the property name will be `"[object Object]"`.

```js
const myKey = {}
const target = { [myKey]: 'value' }
console.log(target)
```

Since, unless you override the `toString` method, every object will have the **same** stringified value, this will not serve your stated needs at all.